# VB.NET use variable in textbox name

Tags: vb.net

OK, so I have a form called quote_guidelines and i would like to use a procedure to update my database with values entered into the quote_guidelines form. The values are the descriptions and costs of decorations, food/drink and entertainment. Each tab has been assigned one of these additional servies. I wanted to make a procedure which would update the database with these new values.
The problem was that the query would have to contain a different table and different textbox names. I tried to solve this by saving the names of the tables and textboxes in variables, which will then be passed into the procedure.

the table variable works fine in the sql statement however, the textbox names dont.
I tried this:

```
quote_guidelines.Controls(description_textbox).Text
```

But this doesnt work.

Here is my query:

```
query = "UPDATE " & additional & " SET description='" & quote_guidelines.Controls("" & description_textbox & "").Text & "', cost= " & quote_guidelines.Controls("" & cost_textbox & "").Text & " WHERE " & additional & "ID='" & y & "'"
```

When I run the program, i get the following error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EHCC_BookingSystem.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I just realised that it might be some other stupid mistake i've made so here's the whole procedure:

```
Sub UpdateAdditionals(textbox3 As System.Object, textbox4 As System.Object, textbox5 As System.Object, textbox6 As System.Object, textbox7 As System.Object, textbox8 As System.Object, ByRef additional As String, ByRef description_textbox As String, ByRef cost_textbox As String)
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=comp4"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    MsgBox(additional & description_textbox & cost_textbox)
    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "UPDATE " & additional & " SET description='" & quote_guidelines.Controls.Find(description_textbox, True).FirstOfDefault().Text & "', cost= " & quote_guidelines.Controls.Find(cost_textbox, True).FirstOfDefault().Text & " WHERE " & additional & "ID='" & y & "'"
        MsgBox(query)
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: If the procedure is a c#/vb.net function you may pass directly the TextBox object or objects

Comment: but the textbox names will be different depending of whether it is decorations, food/drink or entertainment that i am updationg.

Comment: Your question is not clear... you try to get the textbox control by `.Controls(controlname)` ? what do you mean that **the textbox names dont** ?

Comment: What about `quote_guidelines.Controls.Find()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - Replaced `Controls` in `Controls.Find` (Note the `True parameter to search the controls children):

```
query = "UPDATE " & additional & " SET description='" & TryCast(quote_guidelines.Controls.Find(description_textbox, True)(0), TextBox).Text & "', cost= " & TryCast(quote_guidelines.Controls.Find(cost_textbox, True)(0).Text & " WHERE " & additional & "ID='" & y & "'"
```

Also note you could do `.FirstOfDefault()` to get the first control (don't forget to cast):

```
Controls.Find("nameofcontrol", True).FirstOfDefault()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt like that. I got the error message "Arguement not specified for parameter 'searchAllChildren' of 'public function find(key as string,SearchAllChildren AS boolean) as system.windows.control()"

Comment: Strange. That should have worked. I've deleted the double quotes that seemed not necessary. Anyway, this seems the way you should go. You are missing something...

Comment: hmm, i used your most recent eid tof the query and now im getting "text is not a member of system.array"

Comment: You didn't put `.FirstOfDefault()`. Try now my answer.

Comment: Now im getting "FirstOfDefault is not a member of system.array"

Comment: I think you are missing import of `System.Linq`

Comment: Forget it... just make `TryCast(Controls.Find("nameofcontrol", True)(0), TextBox).Text` - THAT HAS TO WORK. Do this for both places where you have the control. Try this and it should work.

Comment: well. it looks good, accept fot the fact the visual studios is insisting that i add a comma on the end... and that will obviously just screw up the rest of the procedure